# Aligning biconditionals in an equational proof

Tags: math-mode, equations

I am trying to obtain this output:

[image]

What I have tried so far:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{array}
  &\iff \neg(A \equiv B)\\
  &\iff \text{axiom}\rangle\\
  &\iff A \equiv B \equiv \bot\\
\end{array}
\end{document}
$

$
```

How can I align every biconditional in the proof ?

P.S: I intend to use it in MathJax.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you so much, Mico !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea if that makes sense but here is something that reproduces your output up to the double arrows where I like `\iff` better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  & \neg(A \equiv B)\\
  \iff & \langle\text{axiom}\rangle\\
  & A \equiv B \equiv \bot\\
  \iff & \langle\text{Leib}+\text{axiom: }B\equiv \bot\equiv \bot\equiv B
   ;\text{ ``$C$-part'' is $A=\mathbf{p}$; $\mathbf{p}$ fresh}\rangle\\
  & A \equiv \bot \equiv B \\
  \iff & \langle\text{Leib}+\text{axiom: }A\equiv \bot\equiv \neg A
   ;\text{ ``$C$-part'' is $B=\mathbf{p}$; $\mathbf{p}$ fresh}\rangle\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would use an `align*` environment, mark the alignment points with `&`, and optionally replace `\iff` width `\Leftrightarrow`. If, for some reason (possibly because you're using MathJax...), you can't use `align*`, it's also possibly to use an `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
                   &\neg(A \equiv B)    \\
\Leftrightarrow  {}&\langle\text{axiom}\rangle \\
                   &A \equiv B \equiv \bot \\
\Leftrightarrow  {}&\langle\text{Leib}+\text{axiom}\colon \dots \\
                   &\dots
\end{align*}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.22} % to mimic the "look" of the 'align' env.
\begin{array}{@{} r @{} l @{}}
                   &\neg(A \equiv B)    \\
\Leftrightarrow{}  &\langle\text{axiom}\rangle \\
                   &A \equiv B \equiv \bot \\
\Leftrightarrow{}  &\langle\text{Leib}+\text{axiom}\colon \dots \\
                   &\dots
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```